# Adjust the the position of an div element when the height of another div element above it is increase dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I want to position a div element when the height of another div element is increased dynamically in other words i don't want the first div element to overlap second div element when its height is increased. How can i do that.

Comment: it's better show your source code

Comment: Please show some effort, search internet, write some code and then come here with something to show so we can help you, writing code for you isn't solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
function f() {
    $(".fchild").height("+=100");
}
```

```css
.parent {
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block
    background-color:blue
}

.fchild {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.cchild {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}

.btn {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="fchild">
</div>
<div class="cchild">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn" onClick="f()">Increase height</button>
```

Notice how, when you press the "Increase height" button, the height of the red box increases, but the green box moves down the same distance. All I have done here is I have put the two divs inside the same parent div, which has a dynamic height.